# Converting to MVC3 - some views still want 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0,

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've used the directions from the release notes and have been able to navigate most pages - my unit tests are not comprehensive but most all pass. However...when I attempt to edit an existing or create a new user I'm getting the error pasted below - notice that it's references version=1... - this project started life as a v1 and was converted to mvc2 at the RTM.

I'm still working with V2 projects but no longer any v1. Am i due for a GAC cleansing?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = STUDIO11\mUser
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/C:\Users\[path to project]/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\[path to project]\bin
Calling assembly : App_Web_qcjylaoc, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\[path to project]\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triple checked and found that while the solution's web.config had the requisite binding redirect nugget, the _project's web.config didn't. Still consider it strange that some pages work while some didn't.